# How can I use native Android Camera App to read barcode/qrcode (no ZXing)?

Tags: android, android-camera, qr-code

I could find a lot of examples of how to read QR Code using ZXing library, however, not a long time ago, Android Camera App started reading these codes nativally, I would like to trigger an Intent or something and be able to retrieve the read QR Code with no need to install or import anything else. The image below shows the result of reading a QR Code on camera app, note that there is a gren circle that if clicked, allows me to copy ot clipboard the QR Code content:

[image]

Comment: I think that native app you're talking about is probably developer by that company whose device you were using. Android's default camera app doesn't do that.

Comment: Humm, I'm running a Moto X 2 gen that is the closest I can get of a pure Android in my country, I somehow thought that it have been a SO new feature. Thanks for clarifying it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will make your app to limit to some devices cause as much as i know not all the devices have this type of native camera app . So you better use Zxing for easy,device independent and reliable app . Have a look at [this](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner).

Answer (score 2):

> Android Camera App started reading these codes nativally

There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread over thousands of device models from hundreds of device manufacturers. There will be dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed camera apps on those devices, as device manufacturers tend to implement their own camera. Of those pre-installed camera apps:

- Few offer QR code scanning
- None that do offer QR code scanning have to offer any sort of API for third-party apps to request QR code scans

In particular, there is nothing in the Android SDK that allows apps to request that third parties scan a QR code.

Comment: I understand that it would not reach nothing near close of the number of devices running android, but that's not my goal. I was just wondering if it is possible to request camera app to read a QR code just like we request Gallery to give us an image Uri.

Comment: @EdgarDaSilvaFernandes: There is nothing in the Android SDK for this. You are welcome to contact the developers of your chosen camera app and ask them if they have a proprietary API that offers this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called [zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) that will read any form of bar-code including **QR**. It is written in pure C for performance and portability . It has wrappers for lots of operating systems and frameworks including [Android](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/AndroidSDK/). It takes up little space and resources and should be easily integrateable within your app.

I have only used it from my Qt5 based app, but it should also be usable directly from native Android.

Building it might require access to the [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html), I am not sure if it comes with pre-built binaries for Android. It has lot's of build time configurations that you can change to remove features and bindings you don't need etc.

I believe the code for Android contains some examples.

Good luck!